# How do I catch an error in an Excel file through Python?

Tags: python, excel

As the title suggests, I'm trying to use Python to catch an excel error that appears when an excel file is opened in Excel.   This is for an ETL that generates a large number of Excel files for output, so opening each by hand to check for issues like this obviously isn't very efficient.  The error I'm seeing looks like this:

[image]

The error gets generated when an earlier part of the script tries to enter a function like

```
=,#
```

into the excel file which obviously doesn't go too well since it starts with an equal sign and then doesn't have an actual function afterwards.  I figure I can use a try/except block, but don't know what I need to make it look for to catch on the exception.

I'm operating on the Databricks platform with the Excel files saving to an S3 bucket in case this matters.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Try a "bare" try/except w/o specifying the exception and print "ERORR". If it can catch the error you'll see the message and can work from there.

Comment: Another way would be to verify the string is valid for excel before writing to the file

Comment: Yea, I've tried the bare try/except block and didn't get anywhere.  And, yea, verifying that the string is valid would be ideal.  But with how often the data changes and how much data there is, it's not practical to code for every situation that could arise.  Based on my research, it doesn't look like what I'm looking for actually exists but wanted to ask around just in case I'm missing something.

Comment: someone made a validaor for excel:
https://github.com/mkesicki/excel_validator